# ExtJs 4 dynamic form fields in nested panels aren't submitted

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4

Let's say I have multiple nested panels (plain ones, not form.Panel) containing form fields.
The user can copy such a panel and its fields to a different panel.

I somehow need to add those newly created fields to a main formpanel so they get submitted, but don't know how.

I can't do

```
formpanel.add(fields)
```

because then they're rendered to the formpanel's body and not the panel they were in in the first place. Setting the fields' renderTo property doesn't help either.

So basically I need a way of adding a field to a normal panel (or any other component for that matter), but also adding it to a specific formpanel so its values are submitted on form submit.

Has anyone done this or could at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all your panels inside one form panel and all the fields inside will be submitted. I did this way with accordeons, tabpanel and normal panels deeply nested inside each other. Example:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    // form attributes goes here...
    // ...
    initComponent: function(){
        // all your panels goes here.
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype:'panel',
                title: 'First panel',
                layout: 'anchor',
                frame: true,
                defaults: {anchor: '100%'},
                items: [
                    {xtype:'textfield', name: 'foo',fieldLabel: 'Foo'},
                    {xtype:'textfield', name: 'foo',fieldLabel: 'Bar'}
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype:'panel',
                title: 'Second panel',
                layout: 'anchor',
                frame: true,
                defaults: {anchor: '100%'},
                items: [
                    {xtype:'textfield', name: 'baz',fieldLabel: 'Baz'},
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        items: [/* another set of fields */]
                    }
                ]
            },
        ];

        this.buttons = [/* ... your buttons here ...*/];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I did wrong was that I created those panels as descendants of a hiddenfield (which contains data for the fields in the panels), which is why the form didn't recognize them. The solution was to make that hidden field add the first panel (which contains the nested panels with fields) to the formpanel and not make it a member of the hidden field.